# Validating a Data Driven Form in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, validation, silverlight-4.0

I have a data driven form generated from database and using DataTemplateSelector for type of questions and I get a run time generated form.

I would like to validate this form. The validation params are also in the db. I have not found any good examples of validation with data driven dynamic forms.

Any link to a good blog/article or code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

are you using mvvm or straight to the database? i have had really good luck with FluentValidation that is available from the NuGet Library. It is very powerful and allows alot of really neat validation logic

Comment: Then I would suggest FluentValidation. You arent really validating the form, you are validating the data in the VM. So nothing should change between which forms are selected in by the template selector